What does <GENxxxx> mean in perl logs?
We have a huge application that very often outputs errors like:
Argument "" isn't numeric in gt (>) at input text line xxx, <GENyyy> line zzz and of course we want to fix them.
But look for example to a line from the logs:
Argument "arbeitet sorgfältig, konzentriert und zuverlässig" isn't numeric in numeric comparison (<=>) at /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/Template/VMethods.pm line 559, <GEN20> line 4.


or a shorter version without VMethods:
Argument "" isn't numeric in numeric gt (>) at input text line 71, <GEN226> line 4.

The problem especially with the second one is that we have absolutely no clue where to look for it and fix it but it produces thousands of logs entries a day. But what is  even? I haven't found any information on the web what it maeans.
So how do I interpret this and how to get more information where this exactly happens. I had one idea of installing a $SIG{___WARN___} handler and print a callstack but it would probably kill the webapp as it would emit thousands of signals then and clutter the logs with callstacks.
Does anybody have a clever idea on how to track down those errors?
Normally perl prints the file & line where this error happens but here it just emits some increasing  number and with various line numbers. So I guess it's different places where it occurs but without further information I can't debug it.

I'd guess this is code form templates, hence no regular file name. You could look at the source of VMethods.pm... looks like a template uses the nsort virtual function, but at least one argument isn't numeric. I'd start with a grep for nsort. Or grep for "arbeitet sorgfältig" and try to find which template works on that. Do you have a dev or test environment with less traffic, so that you can enable debugging? Or can you turn off logging after you've printed the first stack trace?

Well the "arbeitet sorgfältig" comes from the database so nothing to grep for but we might check for nsort. As for dev system, yes we have but we don't know how to reproduce as we don't know where it happens. Disabling stackstrace could be an idea but it would require also some signal handling probably to toggle stacktrace on/off

These generated filehandles are predictably numbered, <GEN226> will be the 226th filehandle created by your code, but of course it's challenging to trace back if they could be created in loops which could have executed multiple times.

https://github.com/Perl/perl5/blob/84564318489ffdf8dcabe85187fe28b06d0c7537/cpan/Module-Metadata/t/taint.t#L25 has an example but it's been so long since I used Perl that I no longer remember how exactly to generate one of these.

@MarcElser The isn't numeric warning comes from using a numeric operator, which assumes both arguments are numerical, but your arguments are not numerical. For example "arbeit...." is not numerical, nor is the empty string. If you try to use that in a variable $foo, e.g. $foo > $bar, you will get that warning. The string will be cast to the first number in the string, which in your cases doesnt exist, so it will be 0. This is a false value in your case. The solution is to find the place in the code which uses numeric comparison and do some argument handling.

<FH> line zzz is added to warnings and exceptions that don't end with a line feed when $. is true.
$. is true after reading a line from a file. It becomes false when EOF is signaled when reading a line, and when close is called. (It's possible that other things close it.)
Symbol's gensym creates handles named GENx. Note that IO::Handle and thus IO::File use gensym.

There are scenarios where Perl invokes gensym on your behalf; it would be useful to havo a rundown of those as well.

It's something like how it tells you (eval 1) for the first eval in your code, (eval 2) for the second etc.

@tripleee Re "There are scenarios where Perl invokes gensym on your behalf", I'm not aware of those.
